# How can I distort a gradient along an axis?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I would like to distort the gradient like the red lines in the image below:
[image]

Comment: Would [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/79163) work for you?

Comment: @user2859 yes this is exactly what I'm looking for! add it as answer so you will get the point! thx!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a **Noise Textures Fac** as input to the texture coordinates of the **Gradient Texture** to get some smooth random distortion:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use **wave texture** with **color ramp**

[image]