# Is it possible to add noise or other type of texture between color ramp stops?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to duplicate the following type of gradient like the horns in this picture:

[image: bull horns]

I saw [an example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/how-can-i-distort-a-gradient-along-an-axis/18383#18383) of that uses a texture as a transition, but it only shown just a duo-tone gradient using a gradient texture. I want to know if is possible to either influence the stops on a color ramp or modify the technique mentioned in the link to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

> It's time to dig this up and make it right.

### Final

[image: final]

### Object and UV Map

Create your horn using chosen technique and **UV Unwrap** it with **Follow Active Quads** as in my answer here: [How to Straighten Curved UVs into Straight Belt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78362#78362)

Using this method is somewhat crucial as we need to have **UV Map** straighten to **X** axis.

[image: objects]

### Material

Extending a bit setup from your link we will make 3 maps. **Base color**, **Roughness** and **Normal** than use them with **Principled Shader**.

For **Base color** we mix main gradient with light and dark spots.

For **Roughness** and **Normal** we will use stretched and mixed **Noise Textures**.

[image: mix]

Most important things here are **Mapping** nodes with stretching along X and Y axis.

[image: Nodes]