# How to Straighten Curved UVs into Straight Belt

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

1. Showing the actual 3D model of a curving ramp.
2. Shows the UVs of that model that blender did automatically.
3. Shows the UV image that I need.

I am going put a road texture on it., but round faces are not helping me at all. All I need is straight belt kind of UV.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41202/935) helpful

Comment: Check my edit to see the difference between two methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LukeD's answer is totally correct, but it can be done faster with fewer steps.

Just select all faces of you object in edit mode, and make sure to Shift-Select one last to make it active.

Press <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads* and be done with it.

If you want the whole UVs to fit into the 0 to 1 UV space then in the *UV image Editor* use the option from the menus UV > Pack Islands.

Rotate, and adjust as needed.

[image]

Comment: This is of course proper answer, but mine is a little bit "properer" I think. Check my edit to see what I mean.

Comment: Ah yes I see now. Fewer steps may come at a cost of more cleanup afterwards.

Comment: I have not used it at all (stretching issues) until I've bumped onto this -
 from manual: "Please note that it is the shape of the active quad in UV space that is being followed, not its shape in 3D space. To get a clean 90-degree unwrap make sure the active quad is a rectangle in UV space before using “Follow active quad”."

Comment: So that must be why I have seen some tutorials advising an *Uwrap > Reset* on the active quad before using the *Active Quads* option. Nice find, I don't unwrap often myself, so I am not very proficient. This is why I love BSE :)

Comment: It's really great method, shame it's so often missed because of unclear usage. I've tried Reset method but it didn't work for me. Can't say why tho.  That's why I've dig about Follow Active Quad and manage to make it this way.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Final]

1. Select all wanted faces and **Unwrap** them.
2. Select one face on the mesh.
3. Align this face in **UV Image Editor** by selecting edges and <kbd>W</kbd> > **Align Auto**.
4. Select all faces on your mesh (keep aligned face as active face).
5. **Unwrap** it by **Fallow Active Quads**.

### Edit:

**Differences between this answer and answer from Duarte Farrajota Ramos.**

As for number of steps it could tempting to believe that fewer is better, but not always. Here is object unwrapped with pure Follow Active Quad > Pack Islands and my method. Not additional steps was taken.

**Duarte Farrajota Ramos answer:**

[image: duarte]

**This answer:**

[image: this]