# UV unwraping a vase

Tags: modeling, uv

How do I properly unwrap this object?

It is a Vase made from circle. I tried all the methods of unwrapping and cylinder projection gives me the best result. However, this stretches the top area. How do I make it consistent like the below?

Reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78362/29370 check my answer here. You will need to use Follow Quad unwrap. In my answer is example with similar shape to vase.

Comment: @LukeD Thanks, it worked, but now the bottom part is stretched :( But I manually adjusted it and it worked well now :)

Comment: Did you marked seams around base part? And one seam trough the mesh? I can't show you now because I'm away from pc. I can make an answer later if you want.

Comment: @LukeD Yeah, sure. There is no base and top. Yes, I made one seam through the mesh.