# UV mapped texture is distorted on flat faces

Tags: modeling, uv

I'm trying to model a hand grenade with my later added hand painted texture. Right now, I'm at the UV Mapping process and I have a problem with stretches appearing on my UV Map.

How can I solve this problem? Is it common? :(

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i unwrapped this with Follow Active Quads and this happened :(

Comment: Check my Follow Active Quads answer from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78362#78362

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the triangulation of the quads:

[image: triangulation of the quads]

You can see how the blue lines "break" (and so the lines in the texture) right where the dotted red lines marking the triangulation are.

The problem is that the UV of these faces is made of squares and rectangles, but the faces in the mesh don't have those shapes anymore.
The solution should be to unwrap the mesh again.