# How to convert UV to square shape?

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

Here, I have tank track model. I'll use this model in the Game, so I will just translate texture to x axis.

[image]

Top and Bottom uv are well mapped, when moving texture to x axis, it's moving circular.

[image]

But the side parts, it's just have same shape, UV doesn't laid out as square like top and bottom faces.

[image]

I tried to make those UV to square just like top and bottom parts, but everything was failed.

How to convert UV of those side faces to square laid out just like top and bototm faces?

Here is the model:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y9HfS_kLRFU52F4GAAysc_km_fSStU0o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Straighten Curved UVs into Straight Belt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt)

Comment: @LukeD I already tried, but doesn't worked. UV doesn't changed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: final]

Method from here: [How to Straighten Curved UVs into Straight Belt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78362#78362) is working just fine, but you have some errors in your model (Interior Faces).

In **Edit Mode**:

1. ***Select*** > ***All by Trait*** > ***Interior Faces***.
2. <kbd>X</kbd> > ***Only Faces***.

[image: x]

This is how to repair your mesh. Now you can use linked method to UV Unwrap it without problem.