# What are the steps to get the UVs back to a square with evenly spaced verts in 2.8?

Tags: uv

I realize there are some things I don't know how to do. I previously had an addon for 2.79 that helped with UV layouts and it isn't available in 2.8. If I have basic shapes with increased detail, what are the steps to get the UVs back to a square with evenly spaced verts? If I'm trying to create a mesh I can use as a base to create vfx.

[image: UV layout]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376#78376