# Something's wrong with the UV map

Tags: uv

[image]

The UV is not Unwrapping into perfect circles. Nothing but mere twists and turns and distort. Can you help me?

SOLVED: I figured out what I did wrong. I used cylinders instead of circle. No wonder why the UV are distorted.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376#78376

Comment: I said perfect circle

Comment: Right you are, must have misread. You prbbaly need to mark some seams, also make sure your scale is applied, or at least uniform across all axis