# How to arrange UV mapping to Square as like attached video?

Tags: uv

At 01:30 on the below video, UVs arranged to Square as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lvpNM1DrYU

If I do follow this action(select all>UV Cylinder Projection), UVs become like below picture(4st).

I would like to know how to fix my UVs as well..

1st picture: modeling
2nd picture: original UVs
3st picture: youtuber's result
4st picture: my result

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Eventhough I used UV Squares, It does not works..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is taken into account when you choose *Unwrap > Cylinder Projection*, you need to be in front orthographic view when you unwrap.

Comment: Wow!!!! Thank you It works for me. Oh my god.!!! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The view doesn't actually matter that much, you can have a perspective view and still get the desired result if you change the *Cylinder Projection* settings to *Align to Object* instead of the default *View on Equator*.

[image: unwrapping]

Comment: Thank you. I notices that I can select Direction also!