# How to make array of textures on torus?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

As shown in this picture
[image]

There are textures on it. I tried to make a boolean of the textures' shape on a torus but it was not good. Is there a better way to make this ring?

Comment: I you use a texture, choose Unwrap > Follow Active Quads mode and you'll get an orthogonal UV, but you're talking about a boolean so it's not clear if you want a texture or if you want to model. If you want to model, you can model it once, array and use the Simple Deform modifier to bend 360°

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/