# Problems when unwrapping the UVs

Tags: uv

guys. I'm new to blender and trying to learn. But I'm having a lot of trouble unwrapping the uv. Whenever I open the shell it gets twisted or crooked. How do I correct it and leave the shell in the correct format? Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: Hello, does it need to be straight? do you plan to project an image on it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376