# Use color ramp to mix materials

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm trying to set up a material that shades the topography of a spherical model of the Earth based on distance to the center of the Earth.  Setting up a ColorRamp based on distance from the center of the sphere is easy:
[image: ColorRamp based on distance to center of sphere]

But each color in the ramp needs a different texture applied to it. In 3ds Max this is done by applying textures to each stop in the Gradient Ramp:
[image: 3ds Max node tree]

Can something similar be done in Blender? I found a [related Blender question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62090/is-it-possible-to-add-noise-or-other-type-of-texture-between-color-ramp-stops), but I can't see how the answer would apply to this situation.

Comment: I hace no clue how to read the nodes from other programs. But if I understand this correctly, you can use the gradient to control the mix between different shaders[blending two textures terrain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109497/blending-two-textures-terrain/109524#109524) To mix more than two shaders concatenate more chanis of ramps and mix nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a color ramp to control the mix between different shaders.

[image]

To mix more shaders use other ramps with different values.

[image]

Comment: Cegaton's node template works splendidly! I test-added a few textures and here's the result:
[![textures added to ColorRamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WU6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WU6.jpg)